# Referencing ROW_NUMBER() in WHERE

Tags: sql, sql-server, function, where-clause, row-number

Having a query that results in over 500K results.  What I want to do is split these up by 100K results.  I created a row number column to help with that, but now that I'm referencing it in my **WHERE** it will not process the function and keep getting this error:

**Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 1
Windowed functions can only appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.**

Query for reference:

```
1  SELECT
2  mt.Name,
3  mt.IDNO,
4  so.IDType,
5  Row   =  ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY mt.Name)
6
7  FROM         MainTable       mt WITH(NOLOCK)
8  LEFT JOIN    SupportTable1   so WITH(NOLOCK) ON  so.Name    = mt.Name
9  LEFT JOIN    SupportTable2   st WITH(NOLOCK) ON  st.Name    = mt.Name
10
11 WHERE    1=1
12 AND      ROW_NUMBER()OVER(ORDER BY mt.Name) BETWEEN '1' and '100000'
```

> ```
> Msg 4108, Level 15, State 1, Line 12 Windowed functions can only
> appear in the SELECT or ORDER BY clauses.
> ```

What can I do to either use this or is there another option to explore that can give me what I need?

Thanks.

Comment: You are not using MySQL.  The code is obviously SQL Server.

Comment: You might check out this article before you continue littering all your queries with NOLOCK hints. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not using MySQL.  In order to do this, use a CTE or subquery:

```
SELECT s.*
FROM (SELECT mt.Name, mt.IDNO, so.IDType, Row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mt.Name)
      FROM MainTable mt LEFT JOIN
           SupportTable1 so 
           ON so.Name = mt.Name LEFT JOIN
           SupportTable2 st
           ON  st.Name = mt.Name
     ) s
WHERE Row BETWEEN 1 and 100000;
```

Notes:

- Window functions cannot be used in the `WHERE` clause.
- Column aliases cannot be used in the `WHERE` clause either; that is why a CTE or subquery is needed.
- Don't put single quotes around integer constants.

Alternatively, you can just use `TOP`:

```
      SELECT TOP (100000) mt.Name, mt.IDNO, so.IDType, Row = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY mt.Name)
      FROM MainTable mt LEFT JOIN
           SupportTable1 so 
           ON so.Name = mt.Name LEFT JOIN
           SupportTable2 st
           ON  st.Name = mt.Name
      ORDER BY Row;
```

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Sql Server 2012, OFFSET and FETCH NEXT were added to the [ORDER BY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql) clause.

```
SELECT mt.Name, mt.IDNO, so.IDType
FROM MainTable mt WITH(NOLOCK)
LEFT JOIN SupportTable1 so WITH(NOLOCK) ON so.Name = mt.Name
LEFT JOIN SupportTable2 st WITH(NOLOCK) ON st.Name = mt.Name
ORDER BY mt.Name OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT 100000 ROWS ONLY;
```

Then add 100000 to the OFFSET number with each new iteration.